# swift compiler error. binary operator == cannot be aplied

Tags: swift

My code is as follows

```
var List_mall_rowid = [Int]()
let mall_rowid = SQL_list?.intForColumn("MH_rowid")
var duplicate: Bool = false 

for rowid in List_mall_rowid{ 
    if rowid == mall_rowid{ 
        duplicate = true 
    }
}
```

but the if statement fails with compiler error

> binary operator == cannot be applied....

I must have tried dozens of different syntax options, getting dozens of errors. What is the correct way to make this comparison?

Answer (score 1):

In your if statement your `rowid` is `Int` type and your `mall_rowid` is another type (I am not sure which type) so you can not compare it and if you want to compare both then both must have same type.

Comment: I doubt that's the solution, as `rowid` is defined in the `for` loop…

Comment: When you do, please include details explaining what is wrong with OP's code and why.

Comment: Sure. I will explain.

Comment: my previous answer fixed your problem?